# Erro ao ler arquivo binário em python

Tags: python, arquivo, python-2.7

boa noite.

Estou tentando ler o conteúdo de um arquivo binário em Python para montar um dicionário, mas ao atingir o final do arquivo o programa está "voando" e não estou conseguindo capturar a exceção. Quando faço o debug, vejo que ele inclui os dados no dicionário corretamente, mas ao chegar na última posição do arquivo, o comando pickle.load(arquivo) "voa" e nenhuma outra linha de código após o while é executada. Nem o comando arquio.close() é executado.

Abrindo o arquivo .dat em um bloco de notas, a exibição dele é semelhante ao seguinte trecho:

```
S'001'
p0
.S'Toninho Silva'
p0
.S'Prefeito'
p0
.S'Tijuca'
p0
.S'2300'
p0
.
```

O código que lê do arquivo binário, grava no dicionário e, ao final, exibe na tela o resultado (que é parte do conteúdo do dicionário) segue abaixo:

```
try:
    dic_votos_candidato = dict()
    arquivo = open('eleicoes.dat', 'rb')
    while arquivo:
        soma = 0
        cod_candidato = pickle.load(arquivo)
        nome_candidato = pickle.load(arquivo)
        cargo = pickle.load(arquivo)
        regiao = pickle.load(arquivo)
        num_votos = pickle.load(arquivo)
        if dic_votos_candidato.get(nome_candidato):
            soma = int(dic_votos_candidato[nome_candidato])
            soma = soma + int(num_votos)
            dic_votos_candidato[nome_candidato] = soma
        else:
            dic_votos_candidato[nome_candidato] = int(num_votos)
    arquivo.close()
    for chave in dic_votos_candidato.keys():
        print chave, dic_votos_candidato[chave]
except IOError:
    print "Erro ao abrir o arquivo. Verifique se o arquivo foi criado."
    print "Caso o arquivo ainda nao exista, use a opcao 1 do menu principal para cria-lo."
    exit()
finally:
    opcao = raw_input('\nPara continuar, digite a opcao desejada: ')
    trata_listar(opcao)
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!